# Embedded Vimeo video glitching with Bootstrap CSS framework

Tags: video, bootstrap-5, vimeo, vimeo-player

I've been trying to embed Vimeo videos in a web page designed using Bootstrap 5.x, and it mostly works, but the video image is almost always glitched when I first load the video, e.g. like this:

https://i.ibb.co/8D59xPg/Screen-Shot-2023-09-25-at-9-44-09.png

Following Vimeo's documentation, I'm building Vimeo's embed iframe dynamically in JScript.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robo007/pe6Lmbh0/6/

I think I've maybe isolated the problem to this DIV:

`<div id="thePlayer" class="ratio ratio-16x9"></div>`

...but after a lot of trial and error, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas...?

Comment: Tried visiting the JSFiddle sample, it works on my end tho and no image glitch is happening. Loaded it a bunch of times and it is good. This may be related on the system environment you are working on and not the vimeo code implementation itself. I tested this on MacOS intel, try opening the JSFiddle on a different device perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for checking, @dale-ryan ! It seems like I need to add an enclosing DIV with a class of **container-fluid**, but I still occasionally see the glitching. It works better with **container-xxl** but that isn't a fluid layout. Puzzling.